# java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, inputstream

On a particular server (Windows 2012 server R2) I am having trouble creating a temp file.  I get the following error everytime I try.

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
etc..
```

The error happens everytime the following code is ran:

`InputStream inputStream = portalBean.createPDF( sessionID, foCode );`

Things I have tried

1. Changed the java.io.tmpdir variable on the fly.  `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "C:\\");`
2. Added `-Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\\temp` to the webnetwork lax file to an unrestricted location.
3. I tried setting the webNetwork service to run as a specified user with rights to temp files e.g. the Administrator.
4. Made sure I have free disk space and I cleaned out the c:\windows\temp folder.
5. Made sure the tmp environment variables were set to their default values.
6. I also tried running the service from a command prompt which was opened with the `Run As Administrator` option.

And the `IOException` lingers still.  I have another server running the same code without issue (Windows Server 2012).

Does anyone else have any Ideas of what else I can try to resolve this issue?  And or any tips on how I can debug the issue more thoroughly to get a grasp of what is going on?

Comment: Is this Java 6 or Java 7?

Comment: @fge Java 7 I believe.

Comment: In the 2012 server, in which folder ere the tmp file located?

Comment: @AndreaTaroni86 by default `C:\Windows\Temp`

Comment: Just one thing, are you sure your code actually uses the temporary directory at all?

Comment: @fge I am not sure if the file gets created in the temporary directory temporarily and then gets moved to it's final destination after.. Maybe not.  I know the `file` or `pdf` in this case gets moved to a `temp/render` folder in another directory once the line of code gets completed..

Comment: So it did work before? Or are there other machines where this code works and it doesn't work on this one?

Comment: @fge Yes this code has worked for years on multiple servers, I believe we just recently upgraded a couple of our servers to Windows Server 2012 R2 and on these servers is where we are getting the error.  I have not had a chance to look into/try the answers yet.  Something else came up at work to resolve first. But i'll try those when I get a chance.

Comment: So it's still a mystery to me, before I could fully look into the problem it seems to have fixed itself.

Answer (score 4):

One tool you can use to debug this is [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from system internal tool kit. The step is: add a filter to only monitor your process (I think it is `javaw.exe` in your case), after the error happens, go through the file activities in the process monitor log, you can find how the process is finding files and which directories the process searched. If the process is searching in the wrong directory, you can find it from the log.

I just used this tool to figure out a JVM crash problem today.

Based on the description of your problem, I guess the path variable of the process is changed in the middle of your code, with another tool [process explore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653) you can view the path variable of the process, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try and create instead a directory somewhere under your home directory:

```
final Path tmpdir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "tmp");
Files.createDirectories(tmpdir);
System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", tmpdir.toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

Then try and `Files.createTempFile()` in there.

Note that if `Files.createDirectories()` refers to an existing file which is not a directory, you'll get a `FileAlreadyExistsException`.